# Listen to realtime updates of a document inside an array in an object with Firestore (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

thanks in advance for your time.

Im trying to listen to realtime updates of a document which lives deep inside after some nested levels.

Is this possible or I should listen to the whole first-level document changes and do the filtering on the client?

This is how my database structure looks:

```
articles: { 
      'article-one': {
          author: "jane doe",
          status: "stock",
          similar: [
             {articleId: "article20", type: "sold"},
             {articleId: "article21", type: "stock"},
             ...
         ]
      }
   }
```

Im trying to listen to realtime updates on the article with 'articleId' of "article20" inside the SIMILAR array.

This is what im trying:

```
const myQuery = query(collection(db, "articles", article-one, "similar"), where("articleId", "==", "article20"));

const unsub = onSnapshot(myQuery, (querySnapshot) => {   
               const selectedArticles = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    selectedArticles.push(doc.data())
                })   
                console.log(selectedArticles);  //output: []  
            })
```

Comment: Is `similar` an array in your document or a sub-collection? The query is looking for documents in `'similar'` sub-collection.

Comment: 'Similar' is an array. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to query elements from an array then that's not possible at the moment. You would have to do either of the following:

1. Fetch the article's documents and filter the array field using Javascript as shown below:

```
const myQuery = doc(db, "articles", article-one);

const unsub = onSnapshot(myQuery, (docSnapshot) => {  
  const similar = docSnapshot.data().similar 
  const selectedArticles = similar.filter(a => a.articleId === "article20")
  console.log(selectedArticles);  
})
```

2. Create a sub-collection "similar" and then use existing query. That should then return documents of all similar articles with given `articleId`.